# Почему вызывается исключение в stdio_common_vfscanf?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При попытке ввода данных в scanf_s столкнулся с проблемой, которую вызывает исключение в файле stdio.h.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>// Standart Input/Output
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h> //Заголовоч. файлы Вин
#include <WinCon.h> //Заг. файлы Вин-консоли
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int num;
char name1[9], name2[9], name3[9];
char type1, type2, type3;
unsigned short kol1, kol2, kol3; 
unsigned long wght1, wght2, wght3;

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251"); //Использование кириллицы 
    printf("1.Введіть: найменування, тип, кількість, вага 1єї деталі\n");
    scanf_s("%s %с %hu %lu", &name1, sizeof(name1), &type1, &kol1, &wght1);//Вводим первую колонку таблицы
    printf("2.Введіть: найменування, тип, кількість, вага 1єї деталі\n");
    scanf_s("%s %с %hu %lu", &name2, sizeof(name2), &type2, &kol2, &wght2);//Вторую
    printf("3.Введіть: найменування, тип, кількість, вага 1єї деталі\n");
    scanf_s("%s %с %hu %lu", &name3, sizeof(name3), &type3, &kol3, &wght3);//Третью
    system("pause");
    }
```

[image: Вызывается данное исключение]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что русская `c` в `%c` - плохая замена латинской `c`...

И еще - спецификатор `%c` в `scanf_s` тоже требует указания размера - 1. (См., например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).)

Так что вызов должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
scanf_s("%s %c %hu %lu", name1, sizeof(name1), &type1, 1, &kol1, &wght1);
```